# How to customize the background color of selected of a Kendo UI Grid row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am a Kendo UI newbie. In my Asp.Net MVC application I use Kendo UI Grid widget and and configure that Grid so user can select a Grid row like:

```
$("#gridSurvey").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/MyController/GetItemList",  

                            ...
                selectable: "row",
                change: function(e)
                {
                    var entityGrid = $("#gridItems").data("kendoGrid");
                    _selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());

                },
                ...
```

By default, when user clicks on a row, the selected row of the selected Grid row is high-lighted with some built-in color.  How can I customize/change that background color of that selected row to transparent or some other color?  I prefer transparent background color.  Please help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
.k-grid .k-state-selected { background: blue; }
```

Comment: for selected row hover color, use this `.k-grid table tr:hover td`

Comment: encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, I was missing this step to get reflect. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547163/changing-the-color-of-onclick-selected-text-in-kendo-angular-grid

Answer (score 2):

```
.k-grid td.k-state-selected:hover, .k-grid tr:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: darkslategray;
}
```

Comment: With current Telerik UI in a .NET Core MVC project, this one worked for me.  The accepted answer did not.